# clang++ with c++11 flag shows rvalue reference cannot bind to lvalue error

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I wrote a simple C++ program t.cpp:

```
// t.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> strVec;
    string a("a");
    strVec.push_back(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I compiled it by clang++ 3.4 on CentOS 6.5 x64. It can be compiled without any error by this command:

```
clang++ t.cpp
```

However, if I turned on the C++11 flag, -std=c++11:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 t.cpp
```

I got a lot of error messages:

```
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:66:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:60:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/move.h:57:14: error: rvalue reference to type 'basic_string<[3 * ...]>' cannot bind to lvalue of type
      'basic_string<[3 * ...]>'
    { return __t; }
             ^~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc:302:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::move<std::basic_string<char> &>' requested here
                                  _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(this->_M_impl._M_finish
                                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/move.h:61:33: note: expanded from macro '_GLIBCXX_MOVE'
#define _GLIBCXX_MOVE(_Tp) std::move(_Tp)
                                ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:741:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::_M_insert_aux<const std::basic_string<char> &>' requested here
          _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
          ^
t.cpp:8:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::push_back' requested here
        strVec.push_back(a);
               ^
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:62:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/allocator.h:48:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++allocator.h:34:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:111:27: error: no matching function for call to 'forward'
        { ::new((void *)__p) _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc:301:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      '__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::basic_string<char> >::construct<std::basic_string<char> >' requested here
          this->_M_impl.construct(this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:741:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::_M_insert_aux<const std::basic_string<char> &>' requested here
          _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
          ^
t.cpp:8:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::push_back' requested here
        strVec.push_back(a);
               ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/move.h:51:5: note: candidate function [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>] not viable: no known conversion
      from 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'typename std::identity<basic_string<char> >::type &&' (aka 'std::basic_string<char> &&') for 1st argument
    forward(typename std::identity<_Tp>::type&& __t)
    ^
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:561:20: error: no matching function for call to 'move'
            *--__result = std::move(*--__last);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:593:45: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__copy_move_backward<true, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_move_b<std::basic_string<char> *, std::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
                                       _Category>::__copy_move_b(__first,
                                                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:602:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__copy_move_backward_a<true, std::basic_string<char> *, std::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
      return _BI2(std::__copy_move_backward_a<_IsMove>
                       ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:674:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__copy_move_backward_a2<true, std::basic_string<char> *, std::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
      return (std::__copy_move_backward_a2<true>
                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc:308:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::move_backward<std::basic_string<char> *, std::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
          _GLIBCXX_MOVE_BACKWARD3(__position.base(),
          ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:679:53: note: expanded from macro '_GLIBCXX_MOVE_BACKWARD3'
#define _GLIBCXX_MOVE_BACKWARD3(_Tp, _Up, _Vp) std::move_backward(_Tp, _Up, _Vp)
                                                    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:741:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::_M_insert_aux<const std::basic_string<char> &>' requested here
          _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
          ^
t.cpp:8:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::push_back' requested here
        strVec.push_back(a);
               ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/move.h:56:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char> &]
    move(_Tp&& __t)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:491:5: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
    move(_II __first, _II __last, _OI __result)
    ^
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:61:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:69:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:916:16: error: rvalue reference to type 'basic_string<[3 * ...]>' cannot bind to lvalue of
      type 'basic_string<[3 * ...]>'
      { return *_M_current; }
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:74:28: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::move_iterator<std::basic_string<char> *>::operator*' requested here
                std::_Construct(&*__cur, *__first);
                                         ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:116:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::uninitialized_copy<std::move_iterator<std::basic_string<char> *>, std::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
        uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result);
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:256:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::uninitialized_copy<std::move_iterator<std::basic_string<char> *>, std::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
    { return std::uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result); }
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:264:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__uninitialized_copy_a<std::move_iterator<std::basic_string<char> *>, std::basic_string<char> *, std::basic_string<char> >' requested here
      return std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_GLIBCXX_MAKE_MOVE_ITERATOR(__first),
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc:339:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__uninitialized_move_a<std::basic_string<char> *, std::basic_string<char> *, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >' requested here
                std::__uninitialized_move_a(this->_M_impl._M_start,
                     ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:741:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::_M_insert_aux<const std::basic_string<char> &>' requested here
          _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
          ^
t.cpp:8:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::push_back' requested here
        strVec.push_back(a);
               ^
In file included from t.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/vector:63:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:73:42: error: no matching function for call to 'forward'
      ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_T2>(__value));
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:74:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::_Construct<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >' requested here
                std::_Construct(&*__cur, *__first);
                     ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:116:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::uninitialized_copy<std::move_iterator<std::basic_string<char> *>, std::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
        uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result);
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:256:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::uninitialized_copy<std::move_iterator<std::basic_string<char> *>, std::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
    { return std::uninitialized_copy(__first, __last, __result); }
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:264:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__uninitialized_copy_a<std::move_iterator<std::basic_string<char> *>, std::basic_string<char> *, std::basic_string<char> >' requested here
      return std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_GLIBCXX_MAKE_MOVE_ITERATOR(__first),
                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/vector.tcc:339:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__uninitialized_move_a<std::basic_string<char> *, std::basic_string<char> *, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >' requested here
                std::__uninitialized_move_a(this->_M_impl._M_start,
                     ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:741:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::_M_insert_aux<const std::basic_string<char> &>' requested here
          _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
          ^
t.cpp:8:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::push_back' requested here
        strVec.push_back(a);
               ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/move.h:51:5: note: candidate function [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>] not viable: no known conversion
      from 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'typename std::identity<basic_string<char> >::type &&' (aka 'std::basic_string<char> &&') for 1st argument
    forward(typename std::identity<_Tp>::type&& __t)
    ^
5 errors generated.
```

One error is:

```
error: rvalue reference to type 'basic_string<[3 * ...]>' cannot bind to lvalue of type
  'basic_string<[3 * ...]>'
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Your code is fine.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b23d2a920336ada) The problem is that you're using too old a version of libstdc++. Either update that or use libc++ instead if you have it installed (add `-stdlib=libc++` to your clang++ invocation).

Comment: Thanks, ildjarn.
Finally, I built a workable libc++ on my CentOS and built my test program t.cpp without error by:
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi t.cpp
This link helps me a lot to build libc++ on CentOS:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917731/what-is-the-sanctioned-way-to-build-libc-for-clang-on-linux